# Select Cells on viewdidload in UITableView, based on String Array (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift2

How can I select multiples cell in UITableview based on match String value within Core Data Array?

I have saved previous selected Rows (As String), but now when I load the table again, I want everything to be selected again. I can't find or think of any solution for this.

**Array:**

```
 var category:[String] = ["News", "Sport", "Weather", "Earth", "Future", "Shop", "TV", "Radio", "Food", "Music", "Travel", "Local", "Nature", "Venue", "Money"]
```

I try to figure out `selectRowAtIndexPath` but I didn't see it in Swift.

Here is how i fetch my Data from Core Data

```
func fetchData(){
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UserSettings", inManagedObjectContext: Context!)
        let request = NSFetchRequest()
        request.entity = entityDescription
        var dataObjects: [AnyObject]?
        do {
            dataObjects = try Context?.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch  let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            dataObjects = nil
        }

        //CAN I UPDATE THE TABLE SELECTION FROM THE FETCH?
        for result in dataObjects as! [NSManagedObject] {
         print(result.valueForKey("favCategory")!)

        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
How can i get this to select base on string stored in Core Data  (Multiple Selection on Viewdidload)

```
 let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0);  //slecting 0th row with 0th section
 self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
```

Comment: what you mean by select？visual effect？

Comment: Not Visual Effect, Actual selection. Okay, I have an array with bunch of values in it (Please see in question), I also have a UITabelView with same group of values that was in array, Now when someone click on each cell the value get stored in core data (I got it until here), Now I want to know how can it be selected even when i left the UITableView and come back for more selection + the ones already stores in core data. I hope I'm clear. I already create a fetch request, and according to that data, those cells should be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not select cells on `viewDidLoad` because the tableView is not loaded as of yet in `viewDidLoad`. You should store a bool variable as a flag in your dataSource, then update your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method as:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

    let object = self.dataObjects[indexPath.row] as! YourObject
    cell.selected = object.isSelected

    return cell
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. It should be called in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: instead